# "People reached" tooltip covered by navigation header

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I was browsing my profile page on the main site, and noticed that the header is overlaying the popup of the "people reached" counter. This does not happen in other websites (but also happens on the Meta profile page).

Browser: Firefox 39.0.3, Windows 10. Don't have any other installed to check.

[image: UX.SE]
[image: Meta.UX.SE]
[image: SO]

In order of appearance: Main, Meta, StackOverflow

It's not a particularly breaking problem, since it only hides a part of the text that is not necessary to understand the metric, but still is weird to look at.

Comment: Reported now in main MSE as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266675/unable-to-read-the-full-content-when-i-moved-the-mouse-curser-over-impactno-of.